# How to prevent an infinite loop with scanf failure

Tags: c, loops, scanf

The Code is supposed to make change for a dollar and works fine. but the professor says that he will be enter random numbers along with letters. It works fine with numbers but when a letter is entered an infinite loop will occur any suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define amtPaid 1
#define SENTINAL -1
int quarters(int numChange);
int dimes(int numChange);
int nickels(int numChange);
int pennies(int numChange);

int main(void)
{
    double amtDue = 0; // how much is paid


while(1){
    printf("\nPlease enter the price less than 1 dollar: ");
    scanf(" %lg", &amtDue);
    int changeReturn = (amtPaid - amtDue) * 100 + 0.5; // convert decimal to whole number
    int updated = 0;    // remaining change after amt of change
    int numberQuarters = quarters(changeReturn); // number of quarters needed

   if(changeReturn >= 0 && changeReturn <= 100){ // if changereturn  is between 0 and 100 execute code

        printf("\nNice!");
        printf("\nWe owe you %i cents" , changeReturn);
        if(numberQuarters >= 0){    // get and print number of quarters
            printf("\nQuarters: %i", numberQuarters);
            updated = changeReturn % 25;
        }
        if(dimes(updated) >= 0){ // get and print number of dimes
            printf("\nDimes: %i", dimes(updated));
            updated = updated % 10;
        }
        if(nickels(updated)>= 0){ // get and print number of nickels
            printf("\nNickels: %i", nickels(updated));
            updated = updated % 5;
        }
        if(pennies(updated) >= 0){ // get and print number pennies
            printf("\nPennies: %i", pennies(updated));
        }

    }

    else if(amtDue == SENTINAL){
        break;
    }

    else {
        printf("That does not make sense to me. please type a valid number");
    }

    printf("\n %g", amtDue);

}
return 0;
}

int quarters(int numChange){
    int numQuarters = 0;

    numQuarters = numChange / 25;

    return numQuarters;
}
int dimes(int numChange){
    int numDimes = 0;

    numDimes = numChange / 10;

    return numDimes;
}
int nickels(numChange){
    int numNickels = 0;

    numNickels = numChange / 5;

    return numNickels;
}
int pennies(numChange){

    return numChange;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case an inappropriate value is supplied other than the expected value of the format specifier with `scanf()`, the `scanf()` will fail and the inappropriate value will *remain* in the input buffer, providing the *feed* to next `scanf()`, only to cause successive failures. In that case, you need to *clean up* the input buffer before going for next input. You can use something like

1. check the return value of `scanf()`
2. In case of failure, use `while( getchar() != '\n' );` to clean the input buffer.

That said, `int nickels(numChange)` is now *invalid* in `c` (`C99` onwards). You have to make it as `int` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `scanf(" %lg", &amtDue);`, get the user input as a string, so you can do proper checking.

```
char input[500];
fgets(input, 500, stdin);

// do some input checking

double val = atof(input);

// do calculations on the number
```

To check, there's all kinds of functions to help you in `ctype.h`, one that you might find interesting is `isalpha`.

---

### Manual References:

- [fgets](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html)
- [atof](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atof.3.html) *converts string to double*
- [atoi](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atoi.3.html) *converts string to integer*
- [isalpha](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isalpha.3.html)